# Modulo in JavaScript - large number

Tags: javascript, integer, modulo

I try to calculate with JS' modulo function, but don't get the right result (which should be 1). Here is a hardcoded piece of code.

```
var checkSum = 210501700012345678131468;
alert(checkSum % 97);

Result: 66
```

Whats the problem here?

Regards,
Benedikt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A bunch of improvements to Benedikt's version: `cRest += '' + cDivident;` is a bugfix; `parseInt(divisor)` makes it possible to pass both arguments as strings; check for empty string at the end makes it always return numerical values; added var statements so it's not using global variables; converted foreach to old-style for so it works in browsers with older Javascript; fixed the `cRest == 0;` bug (thanks @Dan.StackOverflow).

```js
function modulo(divident, divisor) {
  let cDivident = '';
  let cRest = '';

  for (let i in divident) {
    let cChar = divident[i];
    let cOperator = cRest + '' + cDivident + '' + cChar;

    if (cOperator < parseInt(divisor)) {
      cDivident += '' + cChar;
    } else {
      cRest = cOperator % divisor;
      if (cRest == 0) {
        cRest = '';
      }
      cDivident = '';
    }
  }
  cRest += '' + cDivident;
  if (cRest == '') {
    cRest = 0;
  }
  return cRest;
}
```

Comment: Small bug/typo. The final 'cRest == 0' should really be 'cRest = 0'.

Comment: Note that this still does not work for numbers above roughly `2**50` or something. Not sure how to handle this other than using Python where `2**99999 % 7` works just fine. (Note that `**` is to exponentiation, so `2**8==256`.)

Answer (score 19):

For an IBAN calculation form a normal bankaccount number I end up with a very large number contained in a string datatype. From this large number I have to find the rest when divided by 97 -> large number % 97.

As soon as I convert the datatype to an integer I get an overflow resulting in a negative integer and eventually a wrong rest value. As I saw some verbose pieces of code (which also gave wrong outcome), I could not resist to share my own. Credits go to [Finding Modulus of a Very Large Number with a Normal Number](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/39012)

```
modulo: function(divident, divisor) {
    var partLength = 10;

    while (divident.length > partLength) {
        var part = divident.substring(0, partLength);
        divident = (part % divisor) +  divident.substring(partLength);          
    }

    return divident % divisor;
}
```

N.B.
I use 10 positions here as this is smaller than the 15 (and some) positions of max integer in JavaScript, it results in a number bigger than 97 and it's a nice round number. The first two arguments matter.

Comment: This is by far the best solution I could find on the web. Math proof, compatible with every browser, short, easy to be read, simple to apply for IBAN check.

Comment: The hyperlink of the article in the credits was changed. https://www.devx.com/tip-bank/39012/ From the article: "Suppose you need to find nBig % a:

    Take a manageable portion (say, x) of the input large number (nBig) and subtract it from nBig (nBig = nBig – x).
    Compute the mod of x (mod = x % a).
    Add the mod to nBig (nBig = nBig + mod). This way, the number nBig can be reduced without affecting the actual answer."

Answer (score 10):

For those who simply want to copy&paste a working (functional) solution in ES6 to check IBANs:

```
function isIBAN(s){
    const rearranged = s.substring(4,s.length) + s.substring(0,4);
    const numeric   = Array.from(rearranged).map(c =>(isNaN(parseInt(c)) ? (c.charCodeAt(0)-55).toString() : c)).join('');
    const remainder = Array.from(numeric).map(c => parseInt(c)).reduce((remainder, value) => (remainder * 10 + value) % 97,0);

    return  remainder === 1;}
```

You could even write it as a one-liner.

The modulo operation is performed on the array of integers storing the actual number (`divident`, applied as string to function):

```
function modulo(divident, divisor){
   return Array.from(divident).map(c => parseInt(c)).reduce((remainder, value) => (remainder * 10 + value) % divisor,0);
};
```

This works because Modulo is distributive over addition, substraction and multiplication:

- (a+b)%m = ((a%m)+(b%m))%m
- (a-b)%m = ((a%m)-(b%m))%m
- (a*b)%m = ((a%m)*(b%m))%m

The IBAN function transpiled to ES5 looks like:

```
function (s) {
    var rearranged = s.substring(4, s.length) + s.substring(0, 4);
    var numeric = Array.from(rearranged).map(function (c) { return (isNaN(parseInt(c)) ? (c.charCodeAt(0) - 55).toString() : c); }).join('');
    var remainder = Array.from(numeric).map(function (c) { return parseInt(c); }).reduce(function (remainder, value) { return (remainder * 10 + value) % 97; }, 0);
    return remainder === 1;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

looks like you've fallen victim to this: [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to)

just to reiterate what's in the other thread:

> they are 64-bit floating point values, the largest exact integral value is 2^53. however, from the spec section [8.5: Number Type]:
>
> Some ECMAScript operators deal only with integers in the range −2^31 through 2^31−1, inclusive, or in the range 0 through 2^32−1, inclusive. These operators accept any value of the Number type but first convert each such value to one of 2^32 integer values. See the descriptions of the ToInt32 and ToUint32 operators in sections 0 and 0, respectively

But credit where credit is due. Jimmy got the accepted answer over there for doing the legwork (well, googling).

Comment: So, is there a workaround for this? I can't find anything helpful via google.

Comment: Couldn't you do a division and calculate the remainder?

Comment: given that the checksum given above is already above 2^53, you'd have to do something a little more .... interesting... to break up the number *before* performing any operations on it

Answer (score 4):

Finally, my solution:

```
function modulo (divident, divisor) {
    cDivident = '';
    cRest = '';

    for each ( var cChar in divident ) {
        cOperator = cRest + '' + cDivident + '' + cChar;

        if ( cOperator < divisor ) {
            cDivident += '' + cChar;
        } else {
            cRest = cOperator % divisor;
            if ( cRest == 0 ) cRest = '';
            cDivident = '';
        }

    }

    return cRest;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Silent Matt has developed a Javascript [library](http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/)  for Big Integers. It could solve this issue too.

Comment: But this library does not contain a modulo functionality, does it?

Comment: Yes it does, see divRem or remainder