# What does the "|" (single pipe) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(0.5 | 0); // 0
console.log(-1 | 0);  // -1
console.log(1 | 0);   // 1
```

Why does `0.5 | 0` return zero, but any integer (including negative) returns the input integer? What does the single pipe ("|") do?

Comment: It helpfully prevents syntax errors from alerting you to the fact that you typed | instead of ||

Comment: By employing a bitwise OR on a float in this manner, you are basically banking on the immaturity of JavaScript. Python3 would raise the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'int'`

Answer (score 197, accepted):

This is a [bitwise or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29).
Since bitwise operations only make sense on integers, `0.5` is truncated.

`x | 0` is `x`, if `x` is an integer.

Comment: that's an nice way to convert floating-point number to int, or use `parseInt()`

Comment: @MaBi: You should however know that the value is converted to a 32-bit integer, so it won't work properly for larger numbers.

Comment: So can be considered to be same as Floor function?

Comment: Use this only for bitwise or. As @Guffa said, large numbers will not behave as expected. Ex:  248004937500 | 0 = -1103165668

Comment: Large numbers will overflow because they're converted to 32-bit int.

Comment: When people ask me what's the difference between `|` and `||` I always give them this example: `0.5|1` returns 1 and `0.5||1` returns 0.5.

Comment: Use Math.trunc() to trim off the decimal places.  Using the | is dangerous because of overflow errors.  Really nefarious bug to hunt for.

Answer (score 167):

Bit comparison is so simple it's almost incomprehensible ;) Check out this "nybble"

```
   8 4 2 1
   -------
   0 1 1 0 = 6  (4 + 2)
   1 0 1 0 = 10 (8 + 2)
   =======
   1 1 1 0 = 14 (8 + 4 + 2)
```

Bitwise ORing 6 and 10 will give you 14:

```
   alert(6 | 10); // should show 14
```

Terribly confusing!

Comment: Works for Boolean as well. JS interprets true as 1, false as 0; so `alert(true | false) //yields 1; alert(true | true) //yields 1; alert(false | true) //yields 1; alert(false | false) //yields 0`

Answer (score 22):

A single pipe is a [bit-wise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR).

> Performs the OR operation on each pair
> of bits. a OR b yields 1 if either a
> or b is 1.

JavaScript truncates any non-integer numbers in bitwise operations, so its computed as `0|0`, which is 0.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  ("Why does this return 0")

Answer (score 16):

This example will help you.

```js
var testPipe = function(input) { 
   console.log('input => ' + input);
   console.log('single pipe | => ' + (input | 'fallback'));
   console.log('double pipe || => ' + (input || 'fallback'));
   console.log('-------------------------');
};

testPipe();
testPipe('something'); 
testPipe(50);
testPipe(0);
testPipe(-1);
testPipe(true);
testPipe(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Bitwsie OR (|)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR).

The operands are converted to 32-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeroes and ones). Numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant bits discarded.

So, in our case decimal number is converted to interger 0.5 to 0.

```
= 0.5 | 0
= 0   | 0
= 0
```