# Why the value of y changes based on x?

Tags: javascript, math

Below is my code, why does the value of y change?
 
   what does `var y = x | 5;` mean?
 
 
**code**

```
 var x = 0;
      for(x; x < 11 ; x++)
    {
    var y = x | 5;
    console.log("\nx: "+x+ "  y : "+y)
    }
```

The result is

```
    x: 0  y : 5
    x: 1  y : 5
    x: 2  y : 7
    x: 3  y : 7
    x: 4  y : 5
    x: 5  y : 5
    x: 6  y : 7
    x: 7  y : 7
    x: 8  y : 13
    x: 9  y : 13
    x: 10  y : 15
```

why the value of `y` changes based on `x`. 
**On what basics `y` is calculated?**

Comment: is this really a question? If yes, I am shocked.

Comment: The pipe operator has already been discussed:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript

Comment: @FahimParkar yes it is, am dumb in JS. started learning recently.

Comment: I think you should have question heading as **how calculation is done using | operator** and NOT ***WHY.....***

Comment: @FahimParkar I did not know that `|` is an operator in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` is a bitwise OR operator! It works by converting the operands to binary, and doing a OR operation on every bits!

5 in binary is: `101`.
Now, try doing converting the other operand, apply the operation, you will see how `y` is dependent on `x`

For example:

```
9    =   1001
5    =   0101
         ____
9|5  =   1101  == 13
```

---

Also, note that your for-loop contains a syntax error. Remove the last `;` in the line and you are good to go.

```
for(; x < 11 ; x++)
```

Also, you wouldn't need `x` in the first part since it's already declared and initialised

Comment: Glad if that helped. You might want to have a look at AND, OR, XOR truth table also. :)

Comment: the last `;` was a typo error while putting it here.

Answer (score 2):

| is a bitwise OR operator  .It is doing OR operation

This is a bitwise or.
Since bitwise operations only make sense on integers, 0.5 is truncated.

```
0 | x is x, for any x. 

   0 1 1 0 = 6  
   1 0 1 0 = 10 
   1 1 1 0 = 14 

9 | 5 = 1101 (which is 13)
```

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript)

Comment: @VenomVendor did you got the answer now