# What's does the vertical bar mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pipe

I came across this code at school

```
var CAR = ' |8|9|10|11|12|13|15|16|';
```

I understand that this is a variable named car, but I don't understand how it's being initialized or what it means.

Comment: It's just a string. If used in an operation, it's the [bitwise OR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript)

Comment: They mean nothing, they're just a character.

Comment: This is a string, so the `|` is just a `|`

Comment: in logical operation it means `OR` `||` but on the code example it's just a string.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pipe `|` character, and in your case it has absolutely no meaning.  You have a string literal, and the text is literally `|8|9|10|11|12|13|15|16|`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) when used outside the context of a string.  In your case, it's inside a string, so it's probably being used somewhere else in the code as a delimiter of numeric values. ie - 8,9,10,etc.