# what does '|' mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, bit-manipulation

I've seen a single | being used in code somewhere but I have no idea what it means. I know that || is 'or'.

I typed it in the console and these are my results:

```
1 | 0 // 1
0 | 1 // 1
1 | 2 // 3
2 | 4 // 6
```

Does `|` just add the two numbers? Or is there more?

Comment: You've discovered [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), huh?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?  Is that even possible?

Comment: Ah, I fail at searching.   Woooo.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript.

Comment: @BadZen Don't you see I've closed it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way - the single pipe in JavaScript stands for a bitwise or. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29