# get value before point and after point using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

- My value is 13652.598 , i want 2 and 5 from the value.
- I have tried as below but taking from 1, below is my code

---

```
main_value=13652.598
arr = main_value.toString().split(".");
var firstvalue=arr['0'].substring(1,-2);
var secoundtvalue=arr['1'].substring(1,-1);
```

Expected firstvalue is 2 and expected secondvalue is 5.

Comment: Your both variables are named firstvalue

Comment: here's the answer, https://jsfiddle.net/9go0d5na/ without changing your code too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var main_value=13652.598.toString();
var _getIndex = main_value.indexOf('.')
var befChar = main_value.charAt(_getIndex-1);
var AefChar = main_value.charAt(_getIndex+1);
document.write('<pre>'+befChar+' '+AefChar+'</pre>')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/s1kafc4n/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```js
var main_value = 13652.598;
var arr = main_value.toString().split(".");

var firstvalue = arr[0].substring(arr[0].length - 1);
var lastvalue = arr[1].substring(0, 1);

console.log(firstvalue, lastvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mainValue = 13652.598,
    first = mainValue % 10 | 0,
    second = mainValue % 1 * 10 | 0;
console.log(first, second);
```

- [What is the percentage sign / modulus division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work)
- [What does the single pipe do in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript)