# Not Understanding a Portion of a Particular Method to Solve Repeat String JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

while trying to solve a "**repeat a string exercise**", I did some research and came across the following link: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-string-exercise-21.php In that link, the code below is presented as a method for repeating a string. However, I have a question about a **line of code within** that method.

```
function repeat_string(string, count) 
  {
    if ((string == null) || (count < 0) || (count === Infinity) || (count == null))
      {
        return('Error in string or count.');
      }
        count = count | 0; // Floor count.
    return new Array(count + 1).join(string);
  }

console.log(repeat_string('a', 4.6));
console.log(repeat_string('a'));
console.log(repeat_string('a', -2));
console.log(repeat_string('a', Infinity));
```

In the above code, I do not understand what this line of code is saying:

```
count = count | 0; // Floor count.
```

does  `count = count | 0; // Floor count.` mean count is equal to zero after the floor count?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a [bitwise or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29). You can find a more detailed explanation of this here: [What does the “|” (single pipe) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count | 0` is a bitwise or. As a side effect, it will make count an integer. So it's sort of equivalent to `Math.floor(count)`.

**Note**
As @amy points out in a comment below, this construct rounds towards 0. That is: it just removes everything after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

The `|` symbol is [bitwise `or` operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR). Using `| 0` with a positive integer rounds the number down to nearest integer, for example 5.6 | 0 -> 5.

**Note:** `| 0` rounds the number towards 0, so it's equal to Math#ceil when the number is negative, for example -5.6 | 0 -> -5.

**Example:**

```js
var a = 5.6;

console.log(Math.floor(a) === (a | 0));
```

Comment: It doesn't always round down.  It rounds toward zero.  Try `-5.5 | 0`, which gives `-5`.