# JavaScript random number one/zero implementation

Tags: javascript

Hi I found this piece of JS code which generates zero or one: I don't understand how the pipe (ORing) is involved here?

```
  var randomNum = ((Math.random () * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1; // random number between 0 and 1​
```

I found another way

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
```

which accomplishes the same goal. Which one is preferred?

Comment: well, obscurity is usually less good, but that's just my opinion i guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript

Comment: Why the `+ 1) - 1)` I wonder?  Seems like `(Math.random () * 2 | 0)` would be enough on its own.

Comment: For the sake of readability, the second option is better, plus it's less operations so micro-optimized. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/what-does-the-single-pipe-do-in-javascript

Comment: @Dummy - Not useless at all. The bitwise OR first converts the operands to integers.

Comment: @Dummy Not entirely _useless_.  The (desired) side-effect is truncation of the non-zero operand to an integer.  Pretty unreadable code, however.

Comment: Simpler and clearer would be `(Math.random() < 0.5) ? 0 : 1`

Comment: @TedHopp isn't that what the `+` operator is for?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker a ternary never makes things simpler :P

Comment: @Tibrogargan - No. That will leave the result as a floating point number if it started that way.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - Ternary operators tend to mess with predictive instruction pipelines, negatively impacting performance.

Comment: @TedHopp Then I'm going with `~~(Math.random() * 2)`

Comment: @Tibrogargan - Yeah, that's another well-known trick for turning a number into an integer. But it escapes me why anyone would prefer using two bitwise operations when the job can be done using only one, especially if performance is important.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Or just `+(Math.random() < 0.5)`.

Comment: I wouldn't make too many assumptions regarding branch prediction vs bitwise operations in JS, especially with modern optimizing compilers. And I especially wouldn't give it two thoughts unless there were many, many of these numbers being generated.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - Except the `+ 1) - 1;` part isn't needed at all.

Comment: @TedHopp yup.  too small focus.  Wondering if the guy was trying for "random integer between 1 and 2"

Comment: how is fraction represnted in binary? random() gets fraction and result is ORed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"I don't understand how the pipe (ORing) is involved here?"*

The pipe is the bitwise OR operator, and is just used here as a short way to get rid of the fractional part of the random number.

So the random number generates something from `0` to `1.9999999999`, and dropping the decimal gives you `0` or `1`.

> "*Which one is preferred?*"

I'd say clarity if preferred in your general code, so `Math.floor()`.

You could also do this:

```
var randomNum = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: u could also move the more obscure but better performance code into a nicely named function, thereby keeping the code readable.

Comment: True. Some would say that the obscure version should never exist, but I think it's just fine in library code, though I don't know if there's much real benefit to it overall even there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Math.round(Math.random())`, which makes rounding and returns zero and one only. It is equally distributed.

```js
var i = 1e7,
    count = [0, 0];

while (i--) {
    count[Math.round(Math.random())]++;
}

console.log(count);
```