# Operator // in JavaScript : 5.0 // 2.0 = 5?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

Is there a `//` operator in JavaScript?

Because in Python we have:

```py
5 // 2.0 # => 2.0
5 / 2.0  # => 2.5
```

So I tried in JavaScript:

```
5.0//2.0
```

and I got `5`! What's going on there?

I read that there is no such a thing as a `//` operator in JavaScript. In this case, why didn't I get an exception or, better, an error from the lexer?

I used this line:

```
document.write(eval("5.0//2.0"));
```

In Firefox 3.6.23.

Comment: As you might have seen by looking at the syntax highlighting, `// ..` are the markers of a comment in JavaScript. Also, if you need tips for your English, visit http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a question that is answered by its syntax highlighting.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/integer-division-in-javascript) for integer division in JavaScript

Comment: I think Yksin was ashamed of coming back to SO after he saw what his mistake was. @Yksin: come back, choose an answer, we all make silly mistakes

Answer (score 7):

`//` is a comment in javascript.

Try:

```
   5 / 2; //yields 2.5
   Math.floor(5/2); //yields 2
```

---

Also do not use eval.

Just do `document.write(5/2);`

Comment: +1, only answer that mentions what `//` does and how to do integer division.

Comment: what are extra parentheses for in the last line?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins whatever are you talking about?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins that is perfectly fine ^_^

Comment: I've fixed it. Syntax of javascript is too clumsy in my opinion (eg `+a` to convert string to number) to use excess symbols in simple answers.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins ahh that was accidental. Thanks for the fix ^_^

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `//` is not an operator, it denotes a comment.

Answer (score 1):

// is used for commenting in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`//` starts a comment. To do integer division, first perform a regular division using `/` and then round it. This can be done with `&-1`, `^0`, `|0` or `~~`, in order from fast to slow as measured on my laptop. There is a measurable difference between the first three but it's small. The last one is really slow in comparison.

Putting it all together, `5/2&-1` will yield 2. It rounds towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ~~ 5/2 to get 2. NO need to download math. library