# Math - Divide & leave remainder

Tags: jquery, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer division in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/integer-division-in-javascript)

Hopefully this is a simple question, basically I need to do this:

divider = 15

number = 50

Obviously 15 can be divided into 50 3 times with a remainder of 5, is there a simple way I can achieve this with math?

Obviously just dividing 50 by 15 will give me a rounded figure which I just want the lowest possible result and if there is anything left over and it's less than 15 just leave it alone.

Any help?

Cheers, 
Shannon

EDIT:

Thanks to Adil:

```
x = 50;
y = 15;
res = x % y;
x = (x - res) / y;
// x = 3
```

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Just had a look at your link @FelixKling, `Math.floor(y/x)` works perfectly too, didn't even know this existed in javascript.

Cheers

Comment: Also have a look at the comments though, since `.floor` won't work in this case for negative results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9f59bza0%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) `%` to get remainder after division.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XNhec/)**

```
remainder = 50 % 15;
```

Comment: You should get 3 as x-res = 45 and dividing 45 by 15 gets you 3, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XNhec/1/

Answer (score 0):

To get the left over use the modulo. (division remainder)

```
x= 50 % 15
```