# Javascript + math function to exclude a certain number x times

Tags: javascript, function, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer division in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/integer-division-in-javascript)

Lets say I have a specific number.

```
B = 350
```

And I have elements depending on that number, but they all have different amounts of that number in them, like:

```
c = 351,
d = 710,
e = 1100
```

What I want is to be presented by the leftover from dividing the c, d, e with B x times. i.e.

```
c = 1,
d = 10,
e = 50
```

Comment: Have you tried the modulo operator? `351 % 350 = 1; 710 % 350 = 10; 1100 % 350 = 50;`

Comment: Keep in mind that in JavaScript, % is the remainder, not the modulo operation, i.e. `-2 % 5` gives `-2` instead of `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`%` (Modulus)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) Operator.

```
var B = 350, c = 351, d = 710, e = 1100;

console.log(c%B);
console.log(d%B);
console.log(e%B);
```

Taken from mdn:

> The modulus operator returns the first operand modulo the second
>   operand, that is, var1 modulo var2, in the preceding statement, where
>   var1 and var2 are variables. The modulo function is the integer
>   remainder of dividing var1 by var2. For example, 12 % 5 returns 2. The
>   result will have the same sign as var1; that is, −1 % 2 returns −1.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cskvT/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Modulus [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) operator does it:

```
var B = 350,
    c = 351, d = 710, e = 1100;

console.log(c % B, d % B, e % B);  // 1 10 50
```