# How to do integer division in javascript (Getting division answer in int not float)?

Tags: javascript, division, integer-division

Is there any function in Javascript that lets you do integer division, I mean getting division answer in int, not in floating point number.

```
var x = 455/10;
// Now x is 45.5
// Expected x to be 45
```

But I want x to be 45. I am trying to eliminate last digit from the number.

Comment: Have you tried parseInt or Math.floor?

Comment: @SB how ca i use parseInt for this problem.

Comment: @Nakib, `parseInt(455/10);`

Comment: Nakib - you could try `parseInt(x)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/integer-division-in-javascript

Comment: The best way now would be: var x = Math.trunc(455/10);

Answer (score 413, accepted):

```
var answer = Math.floor(x)
```

I sincerely hope this will help future searchers when googling for this common question.

Comment: thanks i googled it but couldn't find, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I find significant irony that this is the top answer in my google search for how to solve this problem.

Comment: I find that this answer is even not correct all the time. If result is negative number, `Math.floor()` returns wrong result. So even Google will return a not-enogh-correct answer. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/integer-division-in-javascript

Comment: usage of `Math.floor()` here is just for the case that given number are positive. [look at this for more explaination](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/floor).
   Normally `parseInt()` is a better choose to get integer part of number or string.

Comment: @ShaunKruger what is ironic, it answer's the q doesn't it? Maybe not very well. Sounds like parseInt is better.

Comment: This did help me :)

Comment: Maybe in ES103 we will  get x \ y to do the other part of x % y ...

Comment: Math.trunc() address the negative value problem. In fact, trunc is what you need if you just want to remove decimal part. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22307150/5876282

Comment: If you want the integer part of A/B to be the quotient Q as in the euclidean division  A = Q.B + R  with 0 <= R < B, then Math.floor() *is* the correct answer also for negative numbers, Math.trunc() would correspond to possibly negative remainders.

Comment: Incorrect answer. I was dividing 2,500,000 by 10,000 - the correct answer is 250. JS made it 249.99999 .... therefore, no, floor would not solve this problem as it would just be 249..

Comment: Is there a shortcut syntax like double slash ```\\``` in Python? If not, RFC ? :)

Comment: @n13 that is unfortunate but I'm not sure there's any way around these sorts of issues, since Javascript doesn't have an actual integer type

Comment: @ICW There's certainly ways to fix it, just saying this is NOT it. This is an incorrect answer that will produce wrong results. Nobody should use this and it should be down voted. Because it's incorrect.

Answer (score 27):

```
var x = parseInt(455/10);
```

> The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.
>
> The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be
>   used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the
>   number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a
>   decimal number.
>
> If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> ```
> If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
> If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
> If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)
> ```

Comment: This is inefficient because it has an implicit `number.toString()` call, folllowed by a `parse` which is relatively expensive compared to `Math.floor`. It is not guaranteed that `parseInt` will accept a `number` argument.

Comment: However this emulates the behavior of python3: `math.inf // 7 == nan` => `parseInt(Infinity / 7) == NaN`

Comment: Emulating `intdiv()` from PHP could be done with something like the following without weird floating point math or other footguns. `const intDiv = (a, b) => (a - a % b) / b;`