# Converting a number to an amount of coins

Tags: javascript

I am creating a program in which I have 3 available currencies, each one takes 100 of the previous to obtain. Using coins for example, I have 145 pennies. How can I convert that to 1 dollar, 45 pennies, or no ten dollar bills, 1 dollar, and 45 pennies?
I have tried to convert the number to a string and use substr() functions determined by the number's length. So if a number was greater than 3 digits, I could not figure out how to take the substr of the 1st digit and last 2 while remaining consistent with all lengths.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Substrings? Why not just use maths, specifically [integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/integer-division-in-javascript) (and remainder).

Comment: I think if the title was changed then this question would be very applicable to many problems faced by new programmers, having said that, a first attempt would have been a good addition to the question

Answer (score 3):

You could use `modulo`, basically finding the remainders of dividing by 100, and 10,000 (100*100).

```
function returnCurrencies(baseCoins)
{
  //Number of bigCoins can be found by subtracting the remainder of % 10000 then dividing by 10000
  var bigCoins = (baseCoins - (baseCoins % 10000))/10000;
  //Now take off the bigCoins from the input
  baseCoins %= 10000;
  //Same for medCoins, but with 100
  var medCoins = (baseCoins - (baseCoins % 100))/100;
  //Now take off the medCoins from the input
  baseCoins %= 100;
  //Whatever is left is the small coins
  return [bigCoins, medCoins, baseCoins];
}

returnCurrencies(145); //[0, 1, 45]
```

**EDIT**

If the modulo thing was not clear, I'll try to explain in more detail:

```
var bigCoins = (baseCoins - (baseCoins % 10000))/10000;
```

This counts the number of big coins in a few steps:

1. Find the number of coins that won't make big coins:

`(baseCoins % 10000)`

This returns the remainder of division, eg `15 % 4 == 3` which is how many coins *won't* make big coins, however we wan't however many will, so...

2. Subtract them from the total:

`baseCoins - (baseCoins % 10000)`

Of course whatever is here will be divisible by 10,000, or a whole number of big coins, leading to the final step:

3. Convert those base coins to big coins:

`(baseCoins - (baseCoins % 10000))/10000`

Because there are 10,000 baseCoins in a bigCoin.

4. Then take all the bigCoins away from baseCoins:

`baseCoins %= 10000`

(This is just the remainder, you could also subtract `bigCoins*10000` from `baseCoins`)

And of course the same applies to medCoins.

Comment: I like how your answer clearly spells out what you're doing and addresses your concern that the OP was from someone new to programming.