# javascript math not working

Tags: javascript, python, math

Why does javascript math operations produce different results than python? and how to fix it?

python:

```
>> 4-((4/3)*3)+1
>> 2
```

javascript:

```
>> 4-((4/3)*3)+1
>> 1
```

Comment: pyhton 3 returns 1.0 / Pyhton 2 returns 2, so the diff is between python- 2 and 3

Comment: even without parentheses, it is in js 1.

Comment: In python, `4/3` will return `1` and not `1.33`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python-division-keeps-rounding

Comment: Arguably the *Python math* "isn't working" here…

Comment: If you want floor division in JavaScript you need to use `Math.floor`, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/integer-division-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually javascript produces decimal values of 1.333333 for 4/3 and it multiplied with 3 which tends to produce 4.
1 is the correct result for 4-((4/3)*3)+1 
but if you want 2 as your result then you need to parse the value of 4/3 to int so 1.333333 will become 1 which is multiplied with 3 will produce 3.

```js
 alert(4-(parseInt(4/3)*3)+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

In python, `4/3 == 1`, since it is an an integer operation. In JS it is a floating point operation, and therefore `4/3 === 1.3333333333333333`.

If you want floating point operations in python, have floating point in the equation. E.g.

`4-((4/3)*3)+1 == 2` (Integer)

`4-((4.0/3.0)*3)+1 == 1` (Float)

Comment: It's even better to do `from __future__ import division` to force Python 2 to do float division.

Comment: Tip for especially lazy readers like myself: you only need one argument to be a float to get floating point division, and a float literal can end with a decimal point, so you can accomplish this by just adding a single dot: `4-((4./3)*3)+1`