# Division and remainder of large numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to get the remainder of a large number, for example:

`1551690021432628813 % 64`

But I find that the it's a couple of digits too long for JavaScript. i.e. it's getting rounded to zero.

Is there a way around this other than using a 26kb library like [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)?

Comment: How are you even representing `1551690021432628813`? As a string?

Comment: @JohnColeman yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could break the number into chunks of 10 digits (from the right) and do the modular arithmetic on the chunks, combining the result at the end:

```
1551690021432628813 = 155169002 * 10**10 + 1432628813
```

Hence

```
1551690021432628813 % 64 = (155169002 % 64 * (10**10) % 64  + 1432628813 % 64) % 64
```

(Which equals `13`).

You could write a recursive function that implements this idea. The following is in Python (which I am more fluent in) but should be easily translated into JavaScript:

```
def remainder(s,m):
    #computes int(s) % m, while just using small numbers
    #s is a string and m is an integer

    n = len(s)
    if n <= 10:
        return int(s) % m
    else:
        first = s[:n-10] #first n-10 digits in s
        second = s[-10:] #last 10 digits
        return (remainder(first,m) * ((10**10) % m) + int(second) % m) % m
```

For the special case that the modulus is `64`, there is an exceptionally easy approach: `64 divides 10**6` so, absolutely always

```
n % 64 == (last 6 digits of n) % 64
```

For example,

```
1551690021432628813 % 64 = 628813 % 64 = 13
```

Similar remarks hold whenever the modulus is a power of 2.

Answer (score 4):

thank you [John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman)

javascript version :

```
    function calculateMod(str, mod) {
        var n = str.length;
        if (n <= 10) {
            return parseInt(str) % mod;
        }
        else {
            var first = str.substring(0, n - 10)
            var second = str.substring(n - 10)
            return (calculateMod(first, mod) * (Math.pow(10, 10) % mod) + parseInt(second) % mod) % mod;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use a library (like that one you found). JavaScript's numbers ([IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double-precision binary floating point) are just not accurate at that scale, and those are the only kind of number JavaScript has*. Once you get past `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1` (9,007,199,254,740,992), JavaScript's numbers cannot represent every integer anymore (for instance, can't represent 9,007,199,254,740,993).

---

* Other than the element type of a typed array, but those don't help you with this for two reasons: 1. There's no typed array for `Uint64`, the biggest integer is `Uint32`, and 2. Once you're performing math operations on the entry, you're converting it to standard number.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can't use a library as large as the ones I've found out there. I guess a good workaround would be a library that only offers the operation I need, i.e. remainder

Comment: @Seano: FWIW, [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) is "8K minified and gzipped." That's nothing in most cases in today's world. (I've never used it, it's just the one I happen to know about.)

Comment: I appreciate that but I can't use gzip. Minified it's still 26kb

Comment: @Seano: You'd have to be using **amazingly** outdated technology not to be able to use gzip; on-the-fly gzip is a web server feature present in any half-decent web server. But their website is well out of date or it's a typo; looks to me like the minified version is 85k which gzips to 19k on the wire. Which is still not big in the modern world -- but it's not 8k, either! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// you can use the built-in BigInt object
console.log(Number(1551690021432628813n % 64n));
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some workarounds, but generally it is easiest to use a library [Read more](http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html)

Comment: The link above axplains how you can implement the "string-based division" manually. Did you consider this approach?

Answer (score -2):

BigInt(1551690021432628813) % 64

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).