# Flatpickr - Is it possible to set time to 15 minute intervals

Tags: flatpickr

Searched for this everywhere and it isn't in the flatpickr options.
I need a way so the user can only select a date in 15 minute intervals.
For example: 12:00 12:15 12:30 12:45 .....

Any help would be great.
Thanks

ref-https://flatpickr.js.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible. flatpickr [minuteIncrement](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/) option can be used to set increment intervals. Also, input time can be restricted between two values as given the example [Time Picker w/ Limits](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/).

Comment: FYI. This option doesn't seem to stop the user from typing an arbitrary time value, it just changes the behaviour of up/down increment arrows

Comment: This doesn't make it 'snap' to those 5 minute increments, though. If the clock starts on 12:43PM, then the button makes it go forward by 5 minutes to 12:48PM. It doesn't snap to 12:45PM and then the next click is to 12:50PM, no.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will ensure that when arbitrary time values are entered, the stepping is enforced. I daresay the code could be a little more concise but hopefully it's clear.  The UX is a bit clunky but it works as expected.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        flatpickr("#myPickerId", {
            enableTime: true, minuteIncrement: 15, onChange: function (dates, dateStr, instance) { flatPickerChange(dates, dateStr, instance); } });
    });

    function flatPickerChange(dates, dateStr, instance) {
        let mi = instance.config.minuteIncrement;
        if (mi && mi > 0) {
            let mins = Number(instance.minuteElement.value);
            if (mins === NaN) return; // Should never happen
            let rem = mins % mi; 
            if (rem === 0) return; // Do nothing if intended stepped value has been selected
            // See Anil Ram's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/how-to-perform-an-integer-division-and-separately-get-the-remainder-in-javascr
            let quot = mins / mi | 0;
            if (rem / mi > 0.5) quot++; // Round up to nearest step if the entered value is closer to upper step rather than lower step
            instance.minuteElement.value = quot * mi;
            instance.setDate(instance.parseDate(dateStr).setMinutes(instance.minuteElement.value)); // Need to explicitly set the date
        }
    }
```