# Numeric overflow in ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, numeric

I'm revisiting an old classic ASP application to add some new requisites, one of them needs to perform an aritmethic operation to generate an id according to some [standard rule for bank files](http://www.dokumentalistas.com/noticias/como-preparar-los-mandatos-sepa-identificador-del-acreedor/) which:

- Generates a number from a long string according to some rules
- Gets mod of dividing this long number by 97
- Substracts this result to 98
- And preppends a 0 if result is only one digit

The number I get as result of first operation is 1185626240142800 (many many magnitudes over max long number), I can convert to Double but then I can't get `mod 97`.

This rule is a standard for bank files so there is no workaround, I need to perform these operations.

In my Windows 7 64 bits I saw I can perform this operation in SQL Server, so as a bad hack it's not a bad idea, any other ideas?

BTW, this app will run on a Windows server 2003 32 bits, in case you think this will be an added problem

Comment: See if this pseudocode helps: http://bytes.com/topic/software-development/insights/793965-how-find-modulus-very-large-number

Comment: Answers are in JavaScript but it is easy to convert them to vbscript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929910/modulo-in-javascript-large-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers larger than `2,147,483,647` cannot fit inside the `Long` datatype. You can implement the [algorithm described in this article](http://bytes.com/topic/software-development/insights/793965-how-find-modulus-very-large-number):

> **Pseudo code:**
>
> To find nBig % a:
>
> Let d = the number of digits that can be processed at a time.
>
> Repeat while val( nBig ) >= a
>   1. tmpStr := d digits from the LHS of nBig.
>   2. nBig := Remaining portion of nBig
>   3. tmpNum := toInteger( tmpStr )
>   4. tmpNum := tmpNum % a
>   5. tmpStr := toString( tmpNum )
>   6. nBig := tmpStr + nBig
>
> Selecting d:
>
> d should satisfy following constraint
>
> max no. of digits in Mod a < d <= max. digits in tmpNum - max no. of digits in Mod a
>   (For eg: If a = 512 (Mod ranges 0..511), and tmpNum can store max 16 digits, then
>   3 < d <= 16-3)
>   (For eg: If a = 100 (Mod ranges 0..99), and tmpNum can store max 16 digits, then
>   2 < d <= 16-2)

**VBScript/VBA Code:**

```
Function LongMod(strDividend As String, numDivisor As Long) As Long

    Dim d As Long
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim numTemp As Long

    d = 9 - Len(CStr(numDivisor - 1))

    While CDbl(strDividend) >= numDivisor
        strTemp = Left(strDividend, d)
        numTemp = CLng(strTemp) Mod numDivisor
        strDividend = CStr(numTemp) & Mid(strDividend, d + 1)
    Wend

    LongMod = CLng(strDividend)

End Function

LongMod("1185626240142800",               97) ' 21
LongMod("330542811101000000123456182900", 97) ' 38
```

Comment: The `Dim [var] As [type]` syntax isn't valid VBScript. I *think* this code will work in VBScript if you simply lose the "`As Long`" and "`As String`" parts (from everywhere, including the function declaration), but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @Martha: correct. The `AS [type]` portions work in VBA and not in VBScript. I've choose to add them so that people can understand what datatype the variables are.