# Summation of a series using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was tackling the problem proposed on HackerRank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/summing-the-n-series/problem) regarding the summation of n terms. I did as follows:

```
 function summingSeries(n) {
    return (n*n) % (10000007);
 }
```

But it does not pass in some cases, would you mind telling what is wrong?

I tried doing exactly the same logic in Java and it worked, how is that even possible?

```
 static BigInteger summingSeries(long n) {
   BigInteger mod = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000007);

   BigInteger number = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
   BigInteger result = number.multiply(number).mod(mod);

   return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "But it does not pass in some cases", what cases?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/2178159

Comment: When n = 681519110

Comment: It has to do with integer overflow in javascript, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929910/modulo-in-javascript-large-number

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't know that, I just spent two hours reviewing the code and my Maths :/

Comment: You should also use correct object type to large numbers calculations, `BigNumber` this case.